# PHP multiple forms, second uses data from the First

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to first, get an ID to query a database and print the results in a table(this part works). I want to then take the id that was given by the user and use it to update the information in the database using PHP. I want to use the input on the second form as the values to update the database with.
The table to alter is `customers` and it has the fields **ID, NAME, ADDRESS.** I do not want the user to be able to change the ID.

Form1:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <p style="margin-top: 70px;">Please type the ID of the person you wish to add to change their data</p>
    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">ID</p>
    <input style="color:black" type="text" name="id" placeholder="10001">
    <input style="color:lightblue;background-color: rgb(80,80,80);margin-top: 7px; " type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Form2:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <p>New Information for Customer with ID entered above</p>
    <input style='color:black;' type='text' name='newName' placeholder='Name Change'>
    <input style="color:black;" type="text" name="newAddress" placeholder="New Address">
    <input style="color:lightblue;background-color: rgb(80,80,80);margin-top: 7px; " type="submit" name="submitForm2" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my current php as requested but it does not work and the $_POST that checks if the values are set returns false.

```
<?php 
            session_start();
            if (isset($_POST["id"])){
                $servername = 'localhost';
                $user = 'root';
                $pass = '';
                $db = 'the_sports_store';
                $conn = new mysqli($servername,$user, $pass, $db);

                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("DB Connection Failed:")';
                    echo '</script>';
                    die("" . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

                $sessionID = $_SESSION["ID"];
                $newName = $_SESSION["newName"];
                $newAddress = $_SESSION["newAddress"];
                var_dump($newName);

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE ID='$sessionID';";


                //display the current record, allow user input to alter it, then display new data
                if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
                    echo"<div class='col-10'>";
                    echo"<table>";
                    echo"<tr>
                            <td align='justify'><b>ID</b></td>
                            <td align='justify'><b>NAME</b></td>
                            <td align='justify'><b>ADDRESS</b></td>
                         </tr>";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                    echo "<tr><td style='padding: 10px;'>{$row['ID']}</td><td>{$row['NAME']}</td><td>{$row['ADDRESS']}</td></tr>";
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo "</div>";





                    if(!empty($_POST["newName"]) && !empty($_POST["newAddress"])){
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert(',$sessionID,');';
                        echo '</script>';
                        $newName = $_POST["newName"];
                        $newAddress = $_POST["newAddress"];
                        $sqlChange = "UPDATE `customers` 
                                        SET `NAME` = '$newName', `ADDRESS` = '$newAddress' 
                                        WHERE `ID` = '$sessionID';";

                        if ($conn->query($sqlChange) === TRUE) {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Update Successful.")';
                            echo '</script>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Error. Update Unsucessful.")';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }

                    }else if(!empty($_POST["newName"])){
                        $newName = $_POST["newName"];
                        $sqlChange = "UPDATE `customers` SET `NAME` = '$newName' WHERE `ID` =  '$sessionID'";
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert(',$newName,');';
                        echo '</script>';

                        if ($conn->query($sqlChange) === TRUE) {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Update Successful.")';
                            echo '</script>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Error. Update Unsucessful.")';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }
                    }else if(!empty($_POST["newAddress"])){
                        $newName = $_POST["newAddress"];
                        $sqlChange = "UPDATE `customers` SET `ADDRESS` = '$newAddress' WHERE `ID` =  '$sessionID'";

                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert(',$sessionID,');';
                        echo '</script>';

                        if ($conn->query($sqlChange) === TRUE) {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Update Successful.")';
                            echo '</script>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<script language="javascript">';
                            echo 'alert("Error. Update Unsucessful.")';
                            echo '</script>';
                        }
                    } else{
                        echo '<script language="javascript">';
                        echo 'alert(',$sessionID,');';
                        echo '</script>';
                    }
                }
                $conn->close();
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: If it's possible add related code!

Comment: use different name for both forms and submit button.

Comment: You are missing an "action" in your second form

Comment: The second form was on the page where the action was sent to. I have since condensed them onto a single page.

Comment: Where do they post though? Is it all just one page and both forms post to themselves?

Comment: This is all one page. I had it broken into 2 at one point but I thought debugging would be easier in 1 page and I'm on a time crunch

Comment: `$sessionID = $_SESSION["ID"];` etc. Do you set them?

Comment: And why even use 2 forms, you could combine them in just one.

Comment: Should there be a $ID = $_POST['id'] ; for each?

Comment: I need to get the ID and display the data before allowing the user to change anything. But if that can be condensed into 1 form please share some code or even pseudo code

Comment: You could definitely condense them, for example you could wrap the "new" buttons into an `if ( $_SERVER ["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) {}` so they would only show after you submit the ID. But you'd also have to change the logic on your PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your PHP code will only execute if the id is set. So the code will never execute when you post the second form.

Move this if `(!empty($_POST["newName"]) && !empty($_POST["newAddress"]))` and all elseif/else below outside of your initial if.

Also, I feel obligated to inform you about SQL Injection and how to avoid it: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: They are already within the first if. Can I use the session variable there instead of just checking if the ID is set?

Comment: I said move them **outside** of the first if. I have no idea how you're using the session variables, are you actually setting them somewhere else?

Comment: I was using the session variable to save the ID entered in the first form so when the page refreshes on submit I keep the value

Comment: How are you doing that? And where? I don't see anything like `$_SESSION["ID"] = $_POST["id"]` anywhere. How to set session variables: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: I know its a security issue, but just connecting to the DB helped! Now I have a problem of an alert that says there was success in the update, but the update did not occur.

Comment: I am also getting an undefined index from id in the second form.

Comment: That probably because you are not setting the session variables anywhere. What is the output of `var_dump($_SESSION);`? Use it just before your first if

Comment: array(1) { ["ID"]=> NULL }  is the result. So when the page is refreshed, the ID  value isn't saved

Comment: Well, yeah, it's not saved by itself, you have to save it yourself. Read the link above regarding session variables and how to use them

Comment: $_SESSION['ID'] = $_POST['id'];
$id = $_SESSION['ID'];

Comment: I used the above and it is transferred to the next page. How can I stop the overwrite that is happening when the next page is submitted? The value is null rather than the entered ID.